# How to leverage Authentication Services to run sudo command in Swift app

Tags: swift, macos, terminal, sudo

so I have a SwiftUI Mac app running a sudo command through `process()` however, as expected, the infrastructure won't let you run that command even with sandbox checked off. I've seen a few resources suggest either using a privileged helper or Authentication services. There's not much documentation on Privileged Helpers, but Authentication Services seems simpler to implement.

I'm not sure how you would implement Authentication Services to run sudo commands though. Have any of you been able to achieve this process? Any input shall be appreciated.

Comment: I've used this [pattern](https://github.com/sveinbjornt/STPrivilegedTask/blob/master/STPrivilegedTask.m) successfully in C In a semi-recent project (2021). I can't tell you if it still works well on modern macOS systems, or if it's feasible to recreate that in Swift.

Comment: IIRC things are less complex than that sample though. You just need `AuthorizationCreate`, `AuthorizationFree` and (the troublesome one)  `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` to run a shell command while prompting the user for authorization.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/trilemma-dev/SwiftAuthorizationSample/tree/main , which uses `SecureXPC` and `Blessed`, two frameworks which wrap these arcane APIs and make them sane to work with. Privileged helpers have a lot of moving parts, and you get near-useless error messages unless you get it all right. Those libraries detect those failure conditions and guide you to fixing it :)

Comment: BTW, you almost certainly don't want to use `sudo` with this. `sudo` is a tool for running programs as root from the command line. You're going to be using a different method to run them as root. You don't need both.

Comment: @GordonDavisson So you're saying I wouldn't wanna use sudo with Auth Services??

Comment: @Mansidak Correct. If you're already using Auth Services to run a command as root, using `sudo` as well is redundant and useless.

Comment: @Alexander nice find, and one of the [dependencies](https://github.com/trilemma-dev/Authorized) is a neat wrapper around `AuthorizationServices`

Comment: Hehe not just a random find, I also contributed a fair bit to SecureXPC